# Play with Google Youtube APIs

Tags: java, playframework, gdata

I'm trying to get a Play! app to get data from Youtube via the GData API. Following the Youtube guide I added

```
import com.google.gdata.client.*;
import com.google.gdata.client.youtube.*;
import com.google.gdata.data.*;
import com.google.gdata.data.geo.impl.*;
import com.google.gdata.data.media.*;
import com.google.gdata.data.media.mediarss.*;
import com.google.gdata.data.youtube.*;
import com.google.gdata.data.extensions.*;
import com.google.gdata.util.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;
```

To the top of my file then created my class

```
public class Videos extends Controller {

    //...Irrelevant stuff...

    public static void create(@Required String video_id) {
        if (validation.hasErrors()) {
            render("Videos/submit.html");
        }

        YouTubeService service = new YouTubeService("app", "abcd");

        String videoEntryURL = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/"+video_id;

        VideoEntry videoEntry = service.getEntry(new URL(videoEntryURL), VideoEntry.class);

        System.out.println(videoEntry.getTitle().getPlainText());
    }

    //...Irrelevant stuff...

}
```

I'm getting the following error from Play

> Compilation error
>
> The file /app/controllers/Videos.java could not be compiled. Error
>   raised is : The type com.google.gdata.client.media.MediaService cannot
>   be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files In
>   /app/controllers/Videos.java (around line 40)
>
> 40: VideoEntry videoEntry = service.getEntry(new URL(videoEntryURL),
>   VideoEntry.class);

In the browser and

> play.exceptions.CompilationException: The type
>   com.google.gdata.client.media.MediaService cannot be resolved. It is
>   indirectly referenced from required .class files  at
>   play.classloading.ApplicationCompiler$2.acceptResult(ApplicationCompiler.java:246)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:474)
>     at
>   play.classloading.ApplicationCompiler.compile(ApplicationCompiler.java:278)
>     at
>   play.classloading.ApplicationClassloader.getAllClasses(ApplicationClassloader.java:412)
>     at play.Play.start(Play.java:485)   at
>   play.Play.detectChanges(Play.java:599)    at
>   play.Invoker$Invocation.init(Invoker.java:186)    at Invocation.HTTP
>   Request(Play!)

From the command line.

I've only recently started using Play! but this error has me stumped =/

I've added the two required librarys from the GData api to the /lib/ folder of my Play! app, the guide I'm following for the GData API is [here](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_java.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

com.google.gdata.client.media.MediaService is in the gdata-media-[version].jar. In my projects, I have five gdata jars: gdata-base, gdata-client, gdata-media, gdata-youtube, and gdata-core.